# How to use setTimeout in the Method intercept() the Http Interceptor

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient-interceptors

I used HttpInterceptor to set the "bearer token" heading to log in Angular, when I log in the server returns a token and I save it in a Response variable but I need a Request variable that is why I use the Intercept.

```
export class TokenInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  intercept(req, next) {

    const tokenizeReq = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        authorization: `Bearer ${this.authService.getToken()}`
      }
    });

    return next.handle(tokenizeReq);
  }

}
```

Image where token is Null in navigator i use Google Chrome

[image: Image where token is Null]

well when i print variables i found  problem i set token when token doesn't exist,

image when print token in intercept

[image]

When i use setTimeout print token correct but i dont know how use in method intercept i have tried different ways  to use this method but when I try to add it I don't know how to use the setTimeout in method intercept()

code when i use setTimeout for print token

```
export class TokenInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  intercept(req, next) {

    const tokenizeReq = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        authorization: `Bearer ${this.authService.getToken()}`
      }
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      const token = this.authService.getToken();
      console.log(token);  
    }, 100);

    return next.handle(tokenizeReq);
  }

}
```

[image]

how to use setTimeout in method intercept() i have tried save in variables but set numbers ( 6, 5 or 9 ) i dont know what to do.

Comment: You haven't told us what the service does, where the token comes from. Probably something is asynchronous; have you tried using observables (or promises)?

Comment: The token is sent by the backend. And I handle promises <any> nothing async

Comment: Give a [mcve], but e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call covers the issue well.

Comment: I'm gonna check it. Thanks!